# Nativescript función asíncrona no espera el return de otra función

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Tengo la siguiente funcion en un componente de nativescript
**login.component.ts**

```
public logIn() {
    this.respuesta = this.colaboroService.EsAccesoValido(this.clave_colaborador, this.password_colaborador);
    console.log(this.respuesta)
}
```

y la siguiente clase donde tengo funciones para el consumo de métodos de un servicio SOAP
**colaboro.service.ts**

```
// Metodo EsAccesoValido   
public EsAccesoValido(cuentaColaborapp: string, contrasenaColaborapp: string) {

    console.log(cuentaColaborapp + " " + cuentaColaborapp)
    var responseXmlFull = "";
    var responseXmlRaiz = "";
    var res: { nombreColaborador: any; };

    var parseString = require('nativescript-xml2js').parseString;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //replace second argument with the path to your Secret Server webservices
    xmlhttp.open('POST', this.url, true);

    //create the SOAP request
    var strRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
        "   <soapenv:Header/>" +
        "   <soapenv:Body>" +
        "      <tem:EsAccesoValido>" +
        "         <tem:xml><![CDATA[<raiz>" +
        "         <cuentaColaborapp>" + cuentaColaborapp + "</cuentaColaborapp>" +
        "         <contrasenaColaborapp>" + contrasenaColaborapp + "</contrasenaColaborapp>" +
        "         </raiz>]]></tem:xml>" +
        "      </tem:EsAccesoValido>" +
        "   </soapenv:Body>" +
        "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    //specify request headers
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IService/EsAccesoValido');

    //FOR TESTING: display results in an alert box once the response is received
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            responseXmlFull = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //Parse responseXmlFull to Json
            parseString(responseXmlFull, function (err, result) {
                responseXmlRaiz = result["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["EsAccesoValidoResponse"][0].EsAccesoValidoResult[0];
            });
            //Parse responseXmlRaiz to Json
            parseString(responseXmlRaiz, function (err, result) {
                res = result["raiz"]["resultado"][0];
                alert(res.nombreColaborador);
                return result["raiz"]["resultado"][0];
            });
        }
    };

    //send the SOAP request
    xmlhttp.send(strRequest);
}
// Metodo EsAccesoValido
```

El problema es que la linea

> console.log(this.respuesta)

no espera por el return de la funcion **EsAccesoValido** ya intente con async/await entre otras cosas pero nada me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a tu problema es la programación reactiva, en este caso basta con regresar un promesa.

```
// Metodo EsAccesoValido   
public EsAccesoValido(cuentaColaborapp: string, contrasenaColaborapp: string) {
    return new Promise((resultado) => {
        console.log(`${cuentaColaborapp} ${cuentaColaborapp}`);
        var responseXmlFull = "";
        var responseXmlRaiz = "";
        var res: { nombreColaborador: any; };

        var parseString = require('nativescript-xml2js').parseString;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //replace second argument with the path to your Secret Server webservices
        xmlhttp.open('POST', this.url, true);

        //create the SOAP request
        var strRequest = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                    <tem:EsAccesoValido>
                    <tem:xml><![CDATA[<raiz>
                    <cuentaColaborapp> ${cuentaColaborapp} </cuentaColaborapp>
                    <contrasenaColaborapp> ${contrasenaColaborapp} </contrasenaColaborapp>
                    </raiz>]]></tem:xml>
                  </tem:EsAccesoValido>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>`;

        //specify request headers
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IService/EsAccesoValido');

        //FOR TESTING: display results in an alert box once the response is received
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                responseXmlFull = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //Parse responseXmlFull to Json
                parseString(responseXmlFull, function (err, result) {
                    responseXmlRaiz = result["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["EsAccesoValidoResponse"][0].EsAccesoValidoResult[0];
                });
                //Parse responseXmlRaiz to Json
                parseString(responseXmlRaiz, function (err, result) {
                    res = result["raiz"]["resultado"][0];
                    alert(res.nombreColaborador);
                    resultado(result["raiz"]["resultado"][0]);
                });
            }
        };

        //send the SOAP request
        xmlhttp.send(strRequest);
    });
}
// Metodo EsAccesoValido
```

Y el resultado lo puedes recuperar de varias formas la que mas se parece a lo que creo que quieres hacer es con async await.

```
  public async logIn() {
    this.respuesta = await this.colaboroService.EsAccesoValido(this.clave_colaborador, this.password_colaborador);
    console.log(this.respuesta);
  }
```

O con `then`

```
  public logIn() {
    this.colaboroService.EsAccesoValido(this.clave_colaborador, this.password_colaborador).then((respuesta) => {
      this.respuesta = respuesta;
      console.log(this.respuesta);
    });
  }
```

Lo importante en este caso es regresar una promesa para que funcione.